# How to design a screen where the user only has very few but important options?

Tags: website-design, page-layout

Alright, I am redesigning a multi-step process where the user adds new contacts to his/her address book.
In the first step, the user chooses between three possible addition methods: file import, crm connector or manual addition.

Now, I am debating how to design this screen. This is my first draft:
[image]

I like how the three huge buttons stand out and draw a lot of attention to the user.
However, compared to the side menu they look incredibly big (too big?).

My question is: How to design a screen like this where the user only has very few but important options?
Small buttons, radio boxes, drop downs, etc. look ridiculous - but is this the way to go?

Any feedback is valuable feedback - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me I would make the buttons rectangular, with the icon on the left and the text on the right. I would also add some short explanation under each button. The windows 8 tile look nice and minimalist, but I noticed that a lot of regular users have problems trying to figure out what does what.